# is it mandatory to recompile body if you recompile specification

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I have one variable in package specification. I am modifying that variable only every time.

Do I need to recompile `body` everytime I do those changes?

Actually I am confused, when you need to recompile `package body`, because i dont compile it in every case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Packages in oracle are stateful in session so you will get package state has been discarded error if you change package specification or body from DB and that package is used in some session in your application. but that is not an issue if the package is currently not being accessed via any of the sessions.

But, If you are talking about the changing of package and package body needs to be re-compiled? --> **Then the answer is no.**

see the small demo here:

**Creating the package specification or body:**

```
SQL> create or replace package p
  2  as
  3  num number := 123;
  4  function f(p_in number) return number;
  5  end p;
  6  /

Package created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace package body p
  2  as
  3  function f(p_in number) return number is
  4  begin
  5  return num;
  6  end f;
  7  end p;
  8  /

Package body created.

SQL>
```

**Calling the function of the package:**

```
SQL> select p.f(2) from dual;

    P.F(2)
----------
       123

SQL>
```

**Changing the package specification:**

```
SQL> create or replace package p
  2  as
  3  num number := 456;
  4  function f(p_in number) return number;
  5  end p;
  6  /

Package created.

SQL>
```

**Calling the function of the package without changing the body:**

```
SQL> select p.f(2) from dual;

    P.F(2)
----------
       456

SQL>
```

Whoop!!! It works.